# pool of images - show only 27 and interchange

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I'm using the following script to read all images off a specified folder:

```
$path= './images/referenzen/*'; 
$files = explode("\n", trim(`find -L $path`));

shuffle($files);

foreach ($files as $item) {
if (preg_match('/\.JPG$/', $item)) {
$pfad = $item; 
$urlarray=explode("/",$pfad);
$end=$urlarray[count($urlarray)-2];

echo '<div class="element-item '.$end.'"><img width="80" src="'.$item.'" /></div>';
}
}
```

By adding this behind the "shuffle"-command

```
$files = array_slice($files, 0, 27);
```

I sometimes get 27 files outputted, but sometimes also only 26, 25 or 24?! This varies, but I don't know why?

Also I'd like to keep the rest of the files in a "pool" and interchange randomly one of the 27 images that get shown on siteload by one of the files off the pool.

So lets say every 20 seconds one randomly picked image of the starting-images should be interchanged by one image off the pool.

I don't know where to start atm. Implementing Javascript would be possible if needed. Anyone got a hint on how to achieve this?

Comment: Where is the definition of `shuffle` function?

Comment: Thx hindmost for commenting! The "shuffle" seems to be a "standard" php-function, I have nothing else added for the shuffle anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

You get less then 27 images because you check if they are JPG after you made them 27 (and probably some of them are not JPG) count them inside the foreach() and break when they are 27.
Also use

```
"/\.jpg\$/i"
```

to check the file extension.

Comment: ah yeah, that's true...before I added the **preg_match** I had some subfolders implemented in the array, so by using the **preg_match** I did get rid of those folders and only images are implemented now. 
The code is off an example from stackoverflow, it had this line: `$path= './images/referenzen/*.jpg';` I thought I could filter by extension, but this didn't work.